# Iterate over a list of quoted strings

Tags: bash, quotes

I'm trying to run a for loop over a list of strings where some of them are quoted and others are not like so:

```
STRING='foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space"'
for item in $STRING; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

Expected result:

```
foo
bar_no_space
baz with space
```

Actual result:

```
foo
"bar_no_space"
"baz
with
space"
```

I can achieve the expected result by running the following command:

```
bash -c 'for item in '"$STRING"'; do echo "$item"; done;'
```

**I would like to do this without spawning a new bash process or using `eval`** because I do not want to take the risk of having random commands executed.

Please note that **I do not control the definition of the STRING variable, I receive it through an environment variable.** So I can't write something like:

```
array=(foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space")
for item in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$item"
done
```

---

If it helps, what I am actually trying to do is split the string as a list of arguments that I can pass to another command.

I have:

```
STRING='foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space"'
```

And I want to run:

```
my-command --arg foo --arg "bar_no_space" --arg "baz with space"
```

Comment: `STRING` is *not* a list of quoted strings; it is a single string. In that string, quotes have no more meaning than any other character.

Comment: Note that `bash -c '...'` is no safer than `eval`; you are still executing arbitrary code.

Comment: @chepner I know `bash -c '...'` will execute the code. Basically I was hoping bash would expose a way to parse the string the way it does internally (because it must do it somehow) but without all the other interpreting features. I guess there is no such thing and I must use a parsing approach outside of bash. I don't really understand all the negative votes though. Are people juste voting down because there is no answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Use an array instead of a normal variable.

```
arr=(foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space")
```

To print the values:

```
print '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

And to call your command:

```
my-command --arg "${arr[0]}" --arg "${arr[1]}" --arg "{$arr[2]}"
```

Comment: I do not control the definition of `STRING`, I receive it through an environment variable.

Comment: @deadbeef Then whoever made the decision to pass a list of arbitrary strings in a single string made a mistake. The design is broken.

Comment: Giving a path as a parameter to a bash script describes exactly this scenario. The design is not broken

Answer (score 2):

## Solved: xargs + subshell

A few years late to the party, but...

Malicious Input:

```sh
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='echo "hello world" foo '"'"'bar'"'"'; sudo ls -lah /; say -v Ting-Ting "evil cackle"'
```

Note: I originally had an `rm -rf` in there, but then I realized that would be a recipe for disaster when testing variations of the script.

Converted perfectly into safe args:

```sh
# DO NOT put IFS= on its own line
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' args=($(echo "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" \
  | xargs bash -c 'for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done'))
echo "${args[@]}"
```

See that you can indeed pass these arguments just like `$@`:

```sh
for arg in "${args[@]}"
do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

Output:

```sh
hello world
foo
bar;
sudo
rm
-rf
/;
say
-v
Ting-Ting
evil cackle
```

I'm too embarrassed to say how much time I spent researching this to figure it out, but once you get the itch... y'know?

## Defeating xargs

It is possible to fool xargs by providing escaped quotes:

```sh
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='\"hello world\"'
```

This can make a literal quote part of the output:

```
"hello
world"
```

Or it can cause an error:

```sh
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND='\"hello world"'
```

```
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

In either case, it doesn't enable arbitrary execution of code - the parameters are still escaped.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure bash parser

Here's a quoted-string parser written in pure bash (what terrible fun)!

*Caveat*: just like the xargs example above, this errors in the case of an escaped quoted.

### Usage

```sh
MY_ARGS="foo 'bar baz' qux * "'$(dangerous)'" sudo ls -lah"

# Create array from multi-line string
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' args=($(parseargs "$MY_ARGS"))

# Show each of the arguments array
for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

Output:

```
$@: foo bar baz qux *
foo
bar baz
qux
*
```

### Parse Argument Function

Literally going character-by-character and adding to the current string, or adding to the array.

```sh
set -u
set -e

# ParseArgs will parse a string that contains quoted strings the same as bash does
# (same as most other *nix shells do). This is secure in the sense that it doesn't do any
# executing or interpreting. However, it also doesn't do any escaping, so you shouldn't pass
# these strings to shells without escaping them.
parseargs() {
    notquote="-"
    str=$1
    declare -a args=()
    s=""

    # Strip leading space, then trailing space, then end with space.
    str="${str## }"
    str="${str%% }"
    str+=" "

    last_quote="${notquote}"
    is_space=""
    n=$(( ${#str} - 1 ))

    for ((i=0;i<=$n;i+=1)); do
        c="${str:$i:1}"

        # If we're ending a quote, break out and skip this character
        if [ "$c" == "$last_quote" ]; then
            last_quote=$notquote
            continue
        fi

        # If we're in a quote, count this character
        if [ "$last_quote" != "$notquote" ]; then
            s+=$c
            continue
        fi

        # If we encounter a quote, enter it and skip this character
        if [ "$c" == "'" ] || [ "$c" == '"' ]; then
            is_space=""
            last_quote=$c
            continue
        fi

        # If it's a space, store the string
        re="[[:space:]]+" # must be used as a var, not a literal
        if [[ $c =~ $re ]]; then
            if [ "0" == "$i" ] || [ -n "$is_space" ]; then
                echo continue $i $is_space
                continue
            fi
            is_space="true"
            args+=("$s")
            s=""
            continue
        fi

        is_space=""
        s+="$c"
    done

    if [ "$last_quote" != "$notquote" ]; then
        >&2 echo "error: quote not terminated"
        return 1
    fi

    for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
    return 0
}
```

I may or may not keep this updated at:

- https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/git-scripts/src/branch/master/git-proxy

Seems like a rather stupid thing to do... but I had the itch... oh well.

Comment: OMG... :) +1 for the perverted fun... I can feel/share your motivation, but there's no way I'd be willing to even look at that code. Not because of you, of course, but because of bash. _(Actually I just did... Couldn't resist. It's not even that horrid...)_

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way without an array of strings or other difficulties (but with bash calling and `eval`):

```
STRING='foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space"'
eval "bash -c 'while [ -n \"\$1\" ]; do echo \$1; shift; done' -- $STRING"
```

Output:

```
foo
bar_no_space
baz with space
```

If You want to do with the strings something more difficult then just `echo` You can split Your script:

**split_qstrings.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

Another part with more difficult processing (capitalizing of `a` characters for example):

```
STRING='foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space"'

eval "split_qstrings.sh $STRING" | while read line 
do
   echo "$line" | sed 's/a/A/g'
done
```

Output:

```
foo
bAr_no_spAce
bAz with spAce
```

Comment: In case it's not clear to others: a downside of this approach (using `eval`) is that if the input string is malicious, it can run arbitrary commands on your system. Eg: the string could have `;` followed by extra commands, which `eval` will run.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
sh-4.4$ echo $string                                                                                                                                                                
foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space"                                                                                                                                                 
sh-4.4$ echo $string|awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)print $i}'|sed '/^ $/d'                                                                                                   
foo                                                                                                                                                                                 
bar_no_space                                                                                                                                                                        
baz with space
```

Comment: That won't work in general: `string='foo "bar_with_\"" "baz with space"'`

Comment: @chepner not tried in a general string.i took the one he provided as an example string . Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is about Bash, but since it's often available in the same places, you might look at Perl's built-in [Text::ParseWords](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords) module to do the heavy lifting, sending the results back to Bash.

Eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

STRING='foo "bar_no_space" "baz with space"'
readarray -t arr < <( perl -MText::ParseWords -e '$,="\n"; print shellwords(@ARGV),"";' "$STRING" )

for item in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$item"
done

# prints:
#   foo
#   bar_no_space
#   baz with space
```

As written, that uses newlines as the delimiter, but you could do whatever you want.
In particular, if your input strings contained raw newlines themselves (inside quotes, for instance), you could use a `NUL` separator or something else pretty easily.

In fact, I'll do that now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

STRING='foo "bar with space" "baz\
with\
newline"'
readarray -t -d '' arr < <( perl -MText::ParseWords -e '$,="\0"; print shellwords(@ARGV),"";' "$STRING" )

for item in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "item: $item"
done

# prints:
#   item: foo
#   item: bar with space
#   item: baz
#   with
#   newline
```

Of course, if your input string has raw `NUL` characters, then it's still potentially a problem (though not a *security* one).

Also beware: if your string has non-matching quote characters, you could get unexpected results.

Even though this is not pure Bash code, I think it is in the spirit of shell scripts to offload the "hard work" to external programs better suited to the task (: